# OpenStack - How to add multiples Floating IP in the same port

Tags: cpanel, openstack, whm

How can I to add two Floating IP(Public) in the same port(interface)? It's Possible?

Example(Port - Eth0):
eth0 - 192.168.1.10 - Public IP 01
eth0:1 - 192.168.1.11 - Public IP 02

** Currently, I can do this only if I add another port(eth1), but it's not resolve my problem because my mailserver(cpanel) accepts adding a second IP only if it is associated with the main interface(eth0).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to add the N number of IPS.
You have to assign fixed IP with exiting primary interface
First, get the Primary IP details ID in order to do that
Here my example, my Primary Instance IP is 20.20.2.10
source project that belong to the instance
`source exampleproject`

To get the ID of the Primary IP 20.20.2.10
`OpenStack port list | grep 20.20.2.10`

`| 1fb8b47d-6eea-511f-8bab-xxxxxxxxxxxxxdd |                 | fa:xx:3e:f7:D5:43 | ip_address='20.20.2.10', subnet_id='44bd275f-desa3-4173-b470-9928ccsdfsddf4' | ACTIVE |`
Now add the IPS as you wish, Here am I adding 20.20.2.11

`openstack port set --fixed-ip subnet=44bd275f-desa3-4173-b470-9928ccsdfsddf4,ip-address=20.20.2.11  1fb8b47d-6eea-511f-8bab-xxxxxxxxxxxxxdd` 
Ensure to check it on OpenStack dashboard static IPs are added

Now Login into the VM, to add eth0:1 or eth0:0 Alias IPS in `**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1**`

```
DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO="static"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
IPADDR=20.20.2.11
GATEWAY=20.20.2.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DNS1=1.1.1.1
DNS2=8.8.8.8
```

Save it and UP the interface alone

**ifup eth0:1**

To add multiple IPs below script to used

```
#!/bin/bash
for octet in {11..21};do
openstack port set --fixed-ip subnet=44bd275f-desa3-4173-b470-9928ccsdfsddf4,ip-address=20.20.2.$octet 1fb8b47d-6eea-511f-8bab-xxxxxxxxxxxxxdd
echo $octet
octet=`expr $octet + 1`
done
```